# C# efficient data model to store data which is transformed though several steps interconnected (as graph)

Tags: c#, performance, memory, datamodel

I'm designing an app where we can have different kind of input sources reading columns and rows (db, csv, excel, etc), the values (cells) can be of any type. And then we have different nodes interconnected that performs operations/transformations over the cells, columns and rows, maybe generating a different types and number of columns, rows and cells. In your experience, which could be the best approach (model) to store in memory this kind of data? It's important to save memory and allow to run calculations using multithreading for a good performance.

Comment: That sounds like Spark.  So you might just use Spark? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/data/spark  Or at least learn how Spark approaches these problems.

Comment: ohh thanks! Sounds very interesting I will take a look, maybe could fit the project needs ;)